# El capitan shell java version doesn't change after updating jdk through Mac Java Control panel

Tags: java, macos

I recently installed New JAVA 1.8_91 by OS X JAVA control panel

after update, from JAVA control panel, it says it successfully installed 1.8.91

but at shell, when i type 'java -version' it says it's old version 1.8.73

i deleted any .bash_profile related to java after update

cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

only had 1.8.0.73 version directory

How do i manage this??

I rebooted computer, restarted shell everything..

Comment: Have you restarted your shell?

Comment: yes i restarted computer and shell

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason why!

OS X's Java control panel is meant to show JRE only

instead, shell was about JDK

I don't know why but it is.

so I'm gonna install JDK 1.8.0.91 from official site.

hope this help someone